# What is wrong with my jquery code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have given my code below,

```
        $(function() {
        $("get-reservation-id").click(function() {
            $(this).load("<%=Url.Action("GetReservation", "ModalPopup") %>", 
            function() {
                $("<div>").dialogr({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 700,
                    title: 'Car Rental Application',
                    modal: true,
                    overlay: {
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        background: "black"
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

This code does not produce a jquery ui dialog pop up.

**get-reservation-id** : is the is given to an image placed within an anchor tag

**GetReservation** : is the partial view

**ModalPopop** : is the name of the controller(Where I have an action that returns GetReservation View)

Any Idea Why this does not work. On the other hand I Have written some code which does work. See Below

Working code:

```
$("#vehicle-search-id").click(function() {
        $("#vehicle-search-id").load("/ModalPopup/VehicleSearch", 
            function() {
                $("#vehicle-search").dialogr({ 
                    width: 700, 
                    modal: false, 
                    title: 'Car Rental Application'
                });
        });
    });
```

The reason why I chose to not use this is because I wanted to use `<%=Url.Action("GetReservation", "ModalPopup") %>` instead of `/ModalPopup/VehicleSearch` and wanted to use a more common `$("<div>").dialogr({` than `$("#vehicle-search").dialogr({`

Many Thanks

**My Aim**

*I want to create a pop up using a Jquery dialog and put a 
partial view in it.*

Comment: Is this code written in an external js file or as inline in the page itself?

Comment: Check your browser for Javascript errors and post them here.

Comment: this is written in an aspx file within a <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the rectified code

```
$(function() {

        $("#get-reservation-id").click(function() {

            $("<div>").dialogr({
                title: 'Title',
                minHeight: 400,
                minWidth: 600,
                width: 800,
                height: 600,
                modal: true,
                open: function() {
                $(this).load('<%= Url.Action("GetReservation", "ModalPopup") %>');
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() { $(this).dialogr("close"); },
                    "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialogr("close"); }
                }
            });
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selectors are of the wrong form. Use `$("#get-reservation-id")` to select the element with that id, and `$("div")` to select all `div` tags.

I also suspect you don't want to select all `div`s in your 5th line, but I don't know what you *do* want to select, so can't really make any suggestions. I suggest you have a look at the [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) documentation.

**Edit:** I think I see what you're doing. You're grabbing the HTML response from `Url.Action("GetReservation", "ModalPopup")` and want to display a modal dialog with contents taken from the (presumably only) `div` in that response.

In that case, you do want `$("div")` on your line 5. Remember that jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors - `$('div')` selects all `div` elements, `$('#foo')` selects the element with id "foo", and `$('.bar')` selects all elements with a class of "bar".

Comment: It kinda looks like he wants to create a new div and put the stuff in it.  But i've never seen it done quite that way before, and i'd be surprised if it worked, as i don't see it ever actually attached to the document.

Comment: I want to create a pop up using a Jquery dialog and put a partial view in it.

Comment: Cant we use something like $('<div>')

Comment: @Haxed - Edited my answer. I'm not familiar with jQuery UI, but I think this is what you want.

Comment: but if u chose $(<div>) you just dont need to specify an id. The benefit of this is in a large application you dont need to change the id all the time depending on the various ids in the partial views. I have posted the anwser.

Comment: Yes, that's fine - but with jQuery `$('<div>')` doesn't select `<div>` elements. `$('div')` does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
$(function() {
    $("get-reservation-id").click(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        that.load('<%=Url.Action("GetReservation", "ModalPopup") %>', 
        function() {
            that.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 700,
                title: 'BMS Car Rental Application',
                modal: true,
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    background: "black"
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed you've got the autoOpen option set to false in your first example. So the first code snippet in your question would create a jQuery dialog, but won't open it. I would suggest either setting autoOpen to true (which is default) or including a line of code to open the dialog elsewhere.